# jQuery(formElement).val(null) : inconsistent results in different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

The code is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jf7t2/1/

Please run it on the latest versions of all browsers, and see for yourself. When the button is clicked, on:

1. on Chrome (and Safari of course) it just doesn't select anything, instead creates some ghostly empty option
2. on Firefox and Opera, it works the way I expect and want it to work, de-selects all options
3. on Internet Explorer, it does nothing

So, which one is the expected behaviour?

Comment: I think the lesson to learn here, is that it doesn't matter what is expected behaviour, none of the browsers conform to them ;)

Comment: Good point, but hard to accept :) It's very short code that potentially can make life simpler, and I am sure the problem is jQuery related, not browser related.

Comment: UPDATE: I apologize, the effect I expected and desired for is NOT resetting the element state, BUT de-selecting all options. Updating question now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the jQuery 1.5.1 source code line 1970 you'll see this:

```
// Treat null/undefined as ""; convert numbers to string
if ( val == null ) {
    val = "";
```

So the expected behavior is the same as if you gave the empty string as argument.

If you continue to line 1984 you'll see this:

```
} else if ( jQuery.nodeName( this, "select" ) ) {
  var values = jQuery.makeArray(val);

  jQuery( "option", this ).each(function() {
    this.selected = jQuery.inArray( jQuery(this).val(), values ) >= 0;
  });
  if ( !values.length ) {
   this.selectedIndex = -1;
  }
```

So the expected behaviour is:

1. if there is an `option` with an empty string value, choose that.
2. if not set `selectedIndex = -1`

From here on it is up to the browser to determine what to do if `selectedIndex` is set to `-1`

Looking at the [msdn library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it says:

> The selectedIndex property returns -1
>   if a select object does not contain
>   any selected items. Setting the
>   selectedIndex property clears any
>   existing selected items.

So in ie the expected behavior seems to be that it will de-select all options

The same goes for the [MDC documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Property/selectedIndex) and thus firefox, where theya re very explicit about it

> Returns the index of the currently
>   selected item. You may select an item
>   by assigning its index to this
>   property. By assigning -1 to this
>   property, all items will be
>   deselected.

It seems webkit based browsers have a different take on things.

If you google "webkit selectedIndex" you will see quite a few bug report regarding the select tag, so maybe it's just funky ;)

Come to think of it, this is a bug in jQuery since it is a library that should be able to behave the same across browsers - it should be reported ;)

Comment: Addendum: So in short, IE doesn't follow its own rules? I mean, as we see, it clearly doesn't de-select all options...

Comment: Well... yes and no - the msdn library only tells us that it will return -1 if nothing is selected, not what setting it to -1 will do... it seems logical that this would deselect it, but then, when has ie even behaved logically? ;) But again, jQuery is a crossbrowser library that should be able to handle this so it works the same in all browsers, obviously this has not be tested well enough, and you should make a  bug report.

Comment: Thx again Martin... I posted this issue in jQuery forum, maybe they will come up with some more decisive solution. Assigning null to SELECT would be quite useful shortcut to deselect its selected options.

Answer (score 2):

> which one is expected behaviour?

jQuery's `val()` function is [documented](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#String,%20Array) to take a string value or an array of string values, so there is no defined behaviour.

Try `val([])` to select nothing, or to restore the original value use the `defaultSelected` property:

```
$('#select option').each(function() {
    this.selected= this.defaultSelected;
});
```

Comment: there is actually a very defined behavior if you read the sourcecode, whether or not it is documented.

Comment: @Martin - I agree... I also read about this (assigning null) in several developer blogs.

Answer (score 1):

I forked your jsfiddle with one that I think can help you:
http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/AYLrT/

I tested it in IE, Firefox and Chrome

```
jQuery("#button").click(function(event){
    var select = jQuery("#select");
    // Button click will try to find a "none" option (with no value)
    if(select.find('option.none').length===0) {
        // If it's not found, it creates the option
        select.prepend('<option value="" class="none"></option>');   
    }
    // And then it selects it
    select.val('');
});

// When select value is changed...
jQuery('#select').change(function() {
    var me = $(this);
    // ... to something different than empty ("")...
    if(me.val() !== '') {
        //... it removes that option
        me.find('option.none').remove();   
    }
});
```

Comment: Thx for the effort, but I am not looking for a solution to any problem :) I am just questioning browser behaviours in case I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

None of those behaviors are unreasonable. 
In Chrome, it makes sense because you are setting the value to nothing, so it displays nothing.
In IE, it makes sense because you are not changing to a valid value, so it changes nothing.

If you want all the browsers to behave like Firefox, just set the value to 1.

Comment: Problem is that the values are unpredictable/dynamic. And I don't want to make code dirtier by making it more complex/slower...

Comment: additionally: Chrome's behaviour doesn't make sense, since it shouldn't introduce new option to SELECT element. IE, I can understand though. Firefox's intuitive behaviour is of course plausible :)